# RegEx with Python: findall inside a boundry

Tags: python, regex, findall

I have a string that can be ilustrated by the following (extraspaces intended):

```
"words that don't matter   START    some words one       some words two     some words three   END    words that don't matter"
```

To grab each substring between START and END `['some words one', some words two', 'some words three']`, I wrote the following code:

```
result = re.search(r'(?<=START).*?(?=END)', string, flags=re.S).group()
result = re.findall(r'(\(?\w+(?:\s\w+)*\)?)', result)
```

Is it possible to achieve this with one single regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the newer [**`regex`**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) module, you can do it in one step:

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|START)\s*\K
(?!\bEND\b)
\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+
```

---

This looks complicated, but broken down, it says:

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|START)  # look for START or the end of the last match
\s*\K               # whitespaces, \K "forgets" all characters to the left
(?!\bEND\b)         # neg. lookahead, do not overrun END
\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+     # your original expression
```

---

In `Python` this looks like:

```
import regex as re

rx = re.compile(r'''
        (?:\G(?!\A)|START)\s*\K
        (?!\bEND\b)
        \w+\s+\w+\s+\w+''', re.VERBOSE)

string = "words that don't matter   START    some words one       some words two     some words three   END    words that don't matter"

print(rx.findall(string))
# ['some words one', 'some words two', 'some words three']
```

---

Additionally, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/oLFVRk/1/).

Comment: This was what I was looking for: a single Regex solution. This is quite recent module, right? I didn't knew about it. I also need to learn about the IF x THEN | ELSE possibilities in Regex.

Comment: @LeandroRibeiro: It is, indeed. Have a look at https://regexone.com/ and http://rexegg.com/ (pretty advanced, but fantastic).

Comment: I changed your Regex [a bit](https://regex101.com/r/oLFVRk/2/). This way it grabs all substrings regardless of number of words. My example had three words substrings, but I need it to match an unknown number of words per string: (?:\G(?!\A)|START)\s*\K
(?!\bEND\b)
\w+(?:\s\w+)*

Comment: Note: At Regex101, this code won't work if I change to Python: (https://regex101.com/r/oLFVRk/3/)

Comment: @LeandroRibeiro: That's true. After all, regex101.com is only an emulator and internally it uses the `re` module. You need to install the `regex` module via `pip install regex` before in order to be able to use it.

Answer (score 2):

In theory you could just wrap your second regex in `()*` and put it into your first. That would capture all occurrences of your inner expression in the bounds. Unfortunately the Python implementation only retains the last match of a group that is matched multiple times. The only implementation that I know that retains all matches of a group is the .NET one. So unfortunately not a solution for you.

On the other hand why can't you simply keep the two step approach that you have?

---

Edit:
You can compare the behaviour I described using online regex tools.

Pattern: `(\w+\s*)*` Input: `aaa bbb ccc`

Try it for example with https://pythex.org/ and http://regexstorm.net/tester.
You will see that Python returns one match/group which is `ccc` while .NET returns `$1` as three *captures* `aaa, bbb, ccc`.

---

Edit2: As @Jan says there is also the newer `regex` module that supports multi captures. I had completely forgotten about that.

Comment: _why can't you simply keep the two step approach that you have?_

I will, but it got me wondering about a possible single Regex pattern that would achieve it, since I'm trying to learn it as best I can.

Intresting: I just realized actually did this with a previous piece of code:

`actors = re.findall(r'Actors[\n\r\t]([\w\s\-\'\,]*)[\n\r\t]Stage', crew)`

This one works, but the source material is slightly different, and I couldn't find a way to make it work with the original example.

Answer (score 0):

This is an ideal situation where we could use a `re.split`, as @PeterE mentioned to circumvent the problem of having access only to the last captured group.

```
import re
s=r'"words that don\'t matter   START    some words one       some words two     some words three   END    words that don\'t matter" START abc  a bc c   END'
print('\n'.join(re.split(r'^.*?START\s+|\s+END.*?START\s+|\s+END.*?$|\s{2,}',s)[1:-1]))
```

Enable a `re.MULTILINE`/`re.M` flag as we are using `^` and `$`.

---

***OUTPUT***

```
some words one
some words two
some words three
abc
a bc c
```

Comment: That's quite elegant. Thank you.